# Detecting odd and even number in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to know if I can make my batch script (`.bat`) to detect if a number is odd or even.
Example: if the imput is an odd number, do this, if even, do that.
This would be very helpfull for my next project.

Thanks!

Comment: modulo is the way to do it, regardless of language. Another way that works in binary computer is to check the least significant bit

Comment: The answer to your question is: we do not know whether ot not you can make it...

Comment: Why didn't you search StackOverflow or Google for **batch file even number**?  You would have found your answer without having to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
set /a dummy=%var% %% 2
if %dummy% == 0 (echo even) else (echo odd)
```

the `%` is a modulus operator and also a special character, hence it needs to be escaped. The escape character for `%` is another `%`.operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator:

```
set number=6
set /a even=number %% 2
if %even%==0 (echo even) else (echo odd)
```

The modulo operator returns the *Rest* of a divison: `5 modulo 2` (or  `5 % 2`) means "five divided by 2 is 2 (which is disregarded) and keeps a rest of 1 (which is your result)".
`<x> modulo <n>` will always return a value between (including) zero and `<n>-1`. For `n=2` that's either zero or one.

Note: although the modulo operator is `%`, you have to escape it with another `%` *in batchfiles*, because of the way, the interpreter processes each line.
In short: directly on command line, use `%`, inside batch files, use `%%`

Answer (score 0):

Batch scripts support the modulo operator `%%`. Here an example:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET /P number=The number is: 
SET /a modulo=%number% %% 2
IF %modulo%==0 (
    ECHO The number is even!
) ELSE (
    ECHO The number is odd!
)
```